# Unable to install gulp-sass on npm version 7.5.1

Tags: npm, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to learn how to use gulp / sass / and all the other tools with Nodejs and I'm having an issue installing gulp-sass. The process I'm using to install everything is:

1. Start terminal in the project folder
2. npm init
3. npm install gulp -g
4. npm install gulp --save-dev
5. npm install gulp-sass <- this is where I get errors

I have a setup of

- OS Popos 20.04
- npm -v 7.5.1
- node -v 15.8.0

Error Log:

```
npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/bin/node /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.8.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:196:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:196:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:196:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:196:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:196:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-7642-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/rashy/Sites/gulp/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rashy/.npm/_logs/2021-02-12T14_21_23_703Z-debug.log
```

I have tried all the available workarounds. I uninstall/reinstall Nodejs, npm but that didn't help. I have tried to install gulp-sass globally. I have also added the latest version of gulp-sass to my package.jason file and npm install but the above error comes every time.

Does anyone have an idea what might be the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but for other reasons you should try `gulp-dart-sass` instead of `gulp-sass`.  It is more up-to-date.

Comment: How did this work? Don't you still need gulp-sass with gulp-dart-sass?

Comment: No it's not required to have both.

Answer (score 1):

That is solved my problem, thank

Working >> `npm install gulp-dart-sass --save-dev` 
**Not working** >> `npm install gulp-sass --save-dev`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dart-sass

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me it was solved when i executed `npm install node-sass gulp-dart-sass --save-dev`